# How to persist the data returned from gesture selector in mobile app - Flutter (Dart)

Tags: flutter, dart

Hi flutter developers,

I am currently building an food bill splitting mobile app using flutter. Now I am facing an issue in persisting the data returned from gesture detector. The functionality is, there will be an elevated button "ADD DISH" which will add and display the food name and its cost as a key value. Under that list of participants names will be displayed wrapped in a row widget. Now using gesture detector i will select the names who are all eating that particular dish. Now the issue is the selection is not getting persisted. after clicking if i move to other page the selection is cleared and data stored in the list becoming empty. I need to persist the data across the page and also if I close the app completely and open it again the selection should persist. The data should be persisted until I clear all the data manually. I will provide the code of the functionality. please help me to solve this
The userBox is Hive userbox contains the participant list and userBox2 is to store the food name and its cost as key value pair.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Hive.initFlutter();
  Hive.registerAdapter(User2Adapter());
  Hive.registerAdapter(User3Adapter());
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class User2 {
  List<Map<String, int>> values;

  User2({required this.values});
}

class User2Adapter extends TypeAdapter<User2> {
  @override
  final int typeId = 1;

  @override
  User2 read(BinaryReader reader) {
    final valuesLength = reader.readByte();
    final values = List<Map<String, int>>.generate(valuesLength,
        (index) => Map<String, int>.from(reader.readMap().cast<String, int>()));
    return User2(values: values);
  }

  @override
  void write(BinaryWriter writer, User2 obj) {
    writer.writeByte(obj.values.length);
    obj.values.forEach((value) => writer.writeMap(value));
  }
}

class User3 {
  Map<String, Set<String>> foodParticipantsMap;

  User3({required this.foodParticipantsMap});
}

class User3Adapter extends TypeAdapter<User3> {
  @override
  final int typeId = 2;

  @override
  User3 read(BinaryReader reader) {
    final foodParticipantsMapLength = reader.readByte();
    final foodParticipantsMap = Map<String, Set<String>>.from(
      reader.readMap().cast<String, Set<String>>(),
    );
    return User3(foodParticipantsMap: foodParticipantsMap);
  }

  @override
  void write(BinaryWriter writer, User3 obj) {
    writer.writeByte(obj.foodParticipantsMap.length);
    obj.foodParticipantsMap.forEach((key, value) {
      writer.writeMapEntry(key, value);
    });
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Hive Example',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyStatefulWidget2(),
    );
  }
}

class MyStatefulWidget2 extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyStatefulWidget2({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyStatefulWidget2> createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState2();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState2 extends State<MyStatefulWidget2> {
  final TextEditingController dishController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController costController = TextEditingController();

  late Box<User2> userBox2;
  late Box<User3> userBox3;

  final List<String> selectbuttonlist = [];
  final List<String> foodbuttonlist = [];
  final List<Set<String>> selectedParticipantsList = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    openBox();
    final userBox = Hive.box<User>('users');
    for (int i = 0; i < userBox.length; i++) {
      foodbuttonlist.add(userBox.getAt(i)!.name);
      selectedParticipantsList.add(Set<String>());
    }
  }

  Future<void> openBox() async {
    userBox2 = await Hive.openBox<User2>('users2');
    userBox3 = await Hive.openBox<User3>('users3');
  }

  void showCustomDialog() {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        String dishValue = dishController.text;
        int costValue = int.tryParse(costController.text) ?? 0;

        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text('Please enter the details'),
          content: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              TextFormField(
                controller: dishController,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Enter your dish',
                ),
                onChanged: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    dishValue = value;
                  });
                },
              ),
              TextFormField(
                controller: costController,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Enter the cost',
                ),
                onChanged: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    costValue = int.tryParse(value) ?? 0;
                  });
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
          actions: [
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                _saveData(dishValue, costValue);
                selectedParticipantsList.add(Set<String>());
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
              child: Text('Add'),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }

  void _saveData(String name, int value) {
    if (name.isNotEmpty && value != null) {
      final values = <Map<String, int>>[
        {name: value}
      ];
      final user = User2(values: values);
      userBox2.add(user);
      setState(() {});
      dishController.clear();
      costController.clear();
    }
  }

  void _deleteData(int index) {
    userBox2.deleteAt(index);
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage('assets/images/food5.jpg'),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Row(
              children: [
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                  child: Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, top: 40),
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        showCustomDialog();
                      },
                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                        primary: Colors.brown,
                      ),
                      child: Text('ADD DISH'),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                  child: Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, top: 40),
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        userBox2.clear();
                        userBox3.clear();
                      },
                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                        primary: Colors.brown,
                      ),
                      child: Text('CLEAR DATA'),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: userBox2.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  final user = userBox2.getAt(index);
                  final keyValuePairs = user!.values;
                  final firstKeyValuePair = keyValuePairs[0];
                  final key = firstKeyValuePair.keys.first;
                  final value = firstKeyValuePair.values.first;
                  final selectedParticipants = selectedParticipantsList[index];
                  return Container(
                    margin:
                        EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0.0, horizontal: 5.0),
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        ListTile(
                          title: Text(
                            '$key  -  $value',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 20,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              color: Colors.black,
                            ),
                          ),
                          trailing: IconButton(
                            icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
                            onPressed: () => _deleteData(index),
                            color: Colors.black,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                          child: Container(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, top: 0),
                            child: Text("Please select the participants:"),
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 10),
                        Wrap(
                          spacing: 15,
                          runSpacing: 10,
                          children: List<Widget>.generate(
                            foodbuttonlist.length,
                            (foodIndex) {
                              final foodName = foodbuttonlist[foodIndex];
                              final isSelected =
                                  selectedParticipants.contains(foodName);

                              return GestureDetector(
                                onTap: () {
                                  setState(() {
                                    if (isSelected) {
                                      selectedParticipants.remove(foodName);
                                    } else {
                                      selectedParticipants.add(foodName);
                                    }
                                  });
                                },
                                child: Container(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    color:
                                        isSelected ? Colors.green : Colors.grey,
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                                  ),
                                  child: Text(
                                    foodName,
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      fontSize: 16,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              );
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```